# Multiple queries in a class based view, how to retrieve and access each query object

Tags: html, django

views.py

```
class Dashboard(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):

def get(self, *args, **kwargs):

    order = Order.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, ordered=True)

    form = BudgetForm()
    b_address = Address.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, address_type='B', default=True)
    s_address = Address.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, address_type='S', default=True)
    budget = Budgets.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
    
    context = {
        'order' : order,
        'b_address' : b_address,
        's_address' : s_address,
        'form' : form,
        'budget' : budget,

    }
    return render(self.request, 'dashboard.html', context)
```

I am passing multiple queries to the class based view but it does not work when I try to access the object of each queries at the front-end. but work when I pass just one to it.
how can I pass all the queries and how can I access each queries object

Answer (score 0):

At the front-end, you can access the queries like this:

```
{% for order in order_queryset %}
  <!-- Display order object properties -->
  <p>{{ order.property }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Beacuse some queries returned may be an array, you should use 'for loop' in django html to extract the value.